# Wiremock stubing multiple URLs giving code 500

Tags: java, request, mocking, wiremock

Im doing some tests were my app takes the value from one initial JSON and, from it, builds URLs and make requests to similar endpoints.

Right now I'm using this function to generate the stubs

```java
  private void prepareURL(String URL) {
    System.out.println("stubFor: http://localhost:8080" + URL);
    stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo(URL)).willReturn(aResponse()
        .withBody(getFileContent(URL))
        .withStatus(200)
    ));
  }
```

Where `getFileContent(String)` just brings a JSON from my testing environment.

The function I'm using to download it the following:

```
  private void testDownload(String url) throws IOException {
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
        .setSocketTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT).build();

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
        .build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
    System.out.println("Downloading "+url+". Code: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
  }
```

This is the Test:

```java
  @Test
  public void anotherTest() throws IOException {
    configureFor("localhost", wireMockServer.port());

    prepareURL("/base-repository.json");
    prepareURL("/wordpress-1.0-template.json");
    prepareURL("/siebel-1.0-template.json");
    prepareURL("/siebel-1.1-template.json");

    testDownload("http://localhost:8080/base-repository.json");
    testDownload("http://localhost:8080/wordpress-1.0-template.json");
    testDownload("http://localhost:8080/siebel-1.0-template.json");
    testDownload("http://localhost:8080/siebel-1.1-template.json");
  }
```

The thing is that, when I run that test, I get the following trace:

```
stubFor: http://localhost:8080/base-repository.json
stubFor: http://localhost:8080/wordpress-1.0-template.json
stubFor: http://localhost:8080/siebel-1.0-template.json
stubFor: http://localhost:8080/siebel-1.1-template.json
Downloading http://localhost:8080/base-repository.json. Code: 200
Downloading http://localhost:8080/wordpress-1.0-template.json. Code: 500
Downloading http://localhost:8080/siebel-1.0-template.json. Code: 500
Downloading http://localhost:8080/siebel-1.1-template.json. Code: 500
```

Meaning that, after the first call, the rest of the stubs aint considered. How can I fix that?

Comment: The problem was related to the size of the responses. Reduce the size of the files that were sent and they all gave code 200.

Comment: Did you by any chance notice what is the approximate maximum size before getting 500?

Comment: I didn't really know to check that using wiremock. I google it but, my ignorance in the tool it's so big that I didn't reach too far @apisim